# Easier way to get view's Id (string) by its Id (int)

Tags: android

I have 24 buttons in my layout, all these buttons do something similar so I want to create a generic function. But first I need to know the name (xml id) of he button.

This the XML code of the button:

```
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/add_04"
      android:layout_width="42dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
      android:background="@xml/zbuttonshape"
      android:onClick="onClick"
      android:text="@string/mas" />
```

I set android:onClick="onClick" for all the buttons.

In my activity I've create a new function onClick:

This the code I've tried:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        String name = v.getContext().getString(v.getId());
        String name2 = context.getString(v.getId());
        String name3 = getString(v.getId());
        String name4 = getResources().getString(v.getId()); 
}
```

But when I try to get the name (in this case "add_04") I always get "false".

Finally I've found a solution with the following code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

String name5 = null;
Field[] campos = R.id.class.getFields();
for(Field f:campos){
     try{
        if(v.getId()==f.getInt(null)){
            name5 = f.getName();
            break;
        }
       }
       catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is there an easier way to get this ID?

Comment: Why do you need to get string id?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The approach is misguided to begin with. If you want to associate a piece of arbitrary data (e. g. a string) with a view, that's what `tag` is for. The ID is numeric and it better stay that way. A word of caution though, tags are not unique in Android, watch for accidental tag collisions within the same view tree.

EDIT much later: the OP's issue was a case of an [XY problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem). That said, the question title *alone* is a legitimate question in its own right.

Comment: Thanks, that what I need. With the property tag I can do it.

String name = v.getTag().toString();

Comment: Android Docs: Unlike IDs, tags are not used to identify views. Tags are essentially an extra piece of information that can be associated with a view. They are most often used as a convenience to store data related to views in the views themselves rather than by putting them in a separate structure.

Comment: view.getResources().getResourceName(view.getId()); Return the full name for a given resource identifier.  This name is a single string of the form package:type/id".

Comment: getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId()); Returns the string representation of the view id only.

Answer (score 166):

like this:

```
/**
 * @return "[package]:id/[xml-id]"
 * where [package] is your package and [xml-id] is id of view
 * or "no-id" if there is no id
 */
public static String getId(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == View.NO_ID) return "no-id";
    else return view.getResources().getResourceName(view.getId());
}
```

I use this in view constructors to make more meaningful TAGs

Comment: came here looking for a way to debug, this answer delivered

Comment: sometime view no id ,this way will get `NotFoundException("Unable to find resource ID #0x" + Integer.toHexString(resid));` exception

Comment: There is a constant for `0xffffffff` called `View.NO_ID` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#NO_ID)

Comment: If misused the getResourceName() method can crash the application when the id is not found.

Answer (score 32):

Edit:

You have to use

`getResources().getResourceEntryName(int resid);`

If you want to retrieve the entry name associated to a resId

or

You can use `getIdentifier()`  to retriece a resource identifier for the given resource name.

For instance:

```
int id = this.getResources().getIdentifier("yourtext", "string", this.getPackageName());
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me - I get 'NullPointerException'  is it always the same package name?

Comment: @GyRo where do you get a `NPE`? Where are you executing that line of code? Are you trying to retrieve a `String` id ?

Comment: The case can be found in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729067/android-increment-button-in-loop-to-setvisibility/28729614#28729614

Comment: You are looking in the wrong class. Use "id" in place of "string"

Comment: What is `yourtext` supposed to be?

Comment: @Ganapolsky is the value of the field "name", for which you want to retrieve the id

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. It is the other way around. OP has the id, and wants to get the field name

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, why? if I have 50 buttons in my application, then I have to set tag for each one and this is not the best approach. However, I can use `getResources().getResourceEntryName(int resid);` to easily get view entry id. +1 for providing this solution

Answer (score 19):

You can check id of each button such way:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.add_04:
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case R.id.add_05:
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what i want!

Answer (score 10):

```
   Use this Approach to get View Id by Programming .
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    />


    String id=getResources().getResourceEntryName(textView.getId());
    Toast.makeText(this,id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You will get Result  ;  tv

Answer (score 7):

You can put this toString() inside an Android View, it will return the String resource Id.

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    Context context;
    Resources r = null;

    context = getContext();

    if (context != null) {
        r = context.getResources();
    }

    String entryName = null;

    if (r != null)
        entryName = r.getResourceEntryName(getId());

    return entryName;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin version (from @gadget) as view extension:

```
val View.stringId: String
    get() {
        return if (this.id == -0x1)
            "no-id"
        else
            this.resources.getResourceName(this.id)
    }
```

Comment: Nice. It's even terser if you use assignment syntax and omit 'this' and 'return'.

`val View.name: String
        get() = if (this.id == -0x1)
            "no-id"
        else
           resources.getResourceEntryName(id) ?: "error-getting-name"`

Answer (score 2):

It's a late answer but may useful someone looking out for a way to get the resource id (int) for any view / drawable / String programmatic.

image from res/drawable

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("my_image", 
            "drawable", getPackageName());
```

view based on resource name

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("my_resource", 
            "id", getPackageName());
```

string

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("my_string", 
            "string", getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @King of Masses is great. Here is my in Kotlin:

**image from res/drawable**

```
val viewId = context.resources.getIdentifier("my_image", "drawable", context.packageName)
```

**view based on resource name**

```
val viewId = context.resources.getIdentifier("my_textview_id", "id", context.packageName)
```

**string**

```
val viewId = context.resources.getIdentifier("my_string", "string", context.packageName)
```

**Layout**

```
val viewId = context.resources.getIdentifier("my_custom_layout", "layout", context.packageName)
```