# Android: Increment Button in loop to setVisibility

Tags: android, loops, button, visibility, visible

I make a game like 4Pics1Word.

Now I have 14 buttons and I want to set the visibility of the Buttons in a loop.

If the answer has 5 letters, the first 5 Buttons should be Visible

For example this is my code:

```
int lengthTest = dataArr.get(currentQuestion)[0].length(); // Get Length of the word from the array.
        for (int nr = 0; nr <= lengthTest; nr++) { // My Loop doesnt work
            answer[nr].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

And that is what I have now, but for 100 Pics it take´s to long to write it every time

```
        answer1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Button1 Visible because the answer length (lengthTest) is 5
        answer2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Button2 Visible
        answer3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Button3 Visible
        answer4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Button4 Visible
        answer5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Button5 Visible
        answer6.setVisibility(View.GONE); //Button6 GONE
        answer7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        answer8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        answer9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        answer10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        answer11.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I hope you understand it sorry for my bad english

Thank you

I got it work, with a Button[] If you want I post the code later.

Thank you all for your help

---

Now I tried this:

```
int lengthTest = dataArr.get(currentQuestion)[0].length() - 1;
        for (int i=1; i<15; i++){
              int buttonId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("answer"+i, "string", this.getPackageName());
              Button currentGameButton = (Button)findViewById(buttonId);
              //now you can do whatever you need for this button, for example
              currentGameButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              // implement checkButtonVisibility to determine whether this button should be VISIBLE or GONE
            }
```

I got this error:

```
02-26 16:08:41.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31838): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

`02-26 16:08:41.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31838): Process: com.developer.flagsofnations, PID: 31838
02-26 16:08:41.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31838): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 16:08:41.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at com.developer.flagsofnations.FlagsOfNations.showQuestion(FlagsOfNations.java:673)
02-26 16:08:41.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at com.developer.flagsofnations.FlagsOfNations$1.onClick(FlagsOfNations.java:196)
02-26 16:08:41.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4480)
02-26 16:08:41.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18686)
02-26 16:08:41.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-26 16:08:41.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-26 16:08:41.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
02-26 16:08:41.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
02-26 16:08:41.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 16:08:41.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-26 16:08:41.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
02-26 16:08:41.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:668)
02-26 16:08:41.429: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

If I use the debugger I can see that buttonId = 0 and currentGameButton = null

I think the problem is here:
Line 673 is `currentGameButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`
because this is 0

Comment: Is all button dynamically created or defined in layout xml file?

Comment: You should add buttons dynamically for that purpose but why don't you use listviews or gridviews after all? These widgets are so easy to use and can help you a lot.

Comment: I create the button´s in xml

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to dynamically create the buttons, then it looks like you should be using a ternary operator.

```
int lengthTest = dataArr.get(currentQuestion)[0].length();
for (int nr = 0; nr < answer.length; nr++) {
    answer[nr].setVisibility((nr < lengthTest)?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Hi if I try your solution, I got the error:  answer cannot be resolved to a variable                                                                                                         I think because the button id is answer1  and not only answer. That I try and it doesn´t work because this I ask here.

Comment: It's a modification of the first code block you posted. I was assuming that `answer` is suppose to be an array of your buttons. What was your purpose in posting that code block?

Answer (score 0):

***Updated on 16/3/15*** (should work now):

Use the Id field of your buttons in order to dynamically change the setting of them from the code. Set the button's IDs using some kind of convention (based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647810/easier-way-to-get-views-id-string-by-its-id-int)).

Meaning, for example, the buttons should be declared in your layout.xml as following:

```
<RelativeLayout...>
  <Button
     android:id="@+id/gameButton1"
     ... />
  <Button
     android:id="@+id/gameButton2"
     ... />
  ...
  <Button
     android:id="@+id/gameButton14"
     ... />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And then your java code that control your buttons can be something like:

```
for (int i=1; i<15; i++){
  int buttonId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("gameButton"+i, "id", this.getPackageName());
  Button currentGameButton = (Button)findViewById(buttonId);
  //now you can do whatever you need for this button, for example
  currentGameButton.setVisibility(checkButtonVisibility(i));
  // implement checkButtonVisibility to determine whether this button should be VISIBLE or GONE
}
```

Let me know if this helps or you have additional questions

Comment: Hi sorry for my late answer I had school until now. If I try your solution, I get the following error:    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Nic I fixed it. (getIdentifiier should have used 'id') It should throw NPE now.