# How to get the name of layout associated with an activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

In `onCreate()` method, we can can use `setContentView(R.layout.something)` to associate a layout to an activity. Is there anyway I could retrieve `something` later for an activity?

I know I can use `this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView()` to get activity's content view but not sure if there anyway from there I can get `something`?

Comment: By "something", do you mean the View's `id` property? If so, it's simply a case of calling `getId()`, which will return the `int` value. To get it as a `String`, use Blackbelt's answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647810/easier-way-to-get-views-id-string-by-its-id-int

Answer (score 2):

When you want to solve it generally for all your activities:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int layoutId;

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        this.layoutId = layoutResID;
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);
    }

    protected String getLayoutName() {
        return getResources().getResourceEntryName(this.layoutId);
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("TAG", getLayoutName());
    }
}
```

Or you can do it simply so:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String layoutName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.layoutName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("TAG", layoutName);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. The problem is I don't have `R.layout.activity_main` and I want to retrieve this later and I can't change the source code as you suggested in the first part.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the root view of your `Activity` using:

```
this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

If you need to get view that you added to your activity using `setContentView()` you can use

```
final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
            .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
```

But you can also use the same id used in the root element of your xml.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to get layout id:

```
this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView().getId()
```

and this to get String:

```
getResources().getResourceName()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Activity extends from View, you shouldn't need to do this. You are, in a way, already referencing the root view inside the activity. That is what allows you to call `findViewById()` any time. If you wanted to find the root element, make sure your root (LinearLayout or RelativeLayout) has an id, and you could do something like:

```
LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_root);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `setConetentView(R.layout.content)` in any method in any activity, as long as `content.xml` exists as a layout file in the layout directory.

> An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do. Almost
>   all activities interact with the user, so the Activity class takes
>   care of creating a window for you in which you can place your UI with
>   setContentView(View). While activities are often presented to the user
>   as full-screen windows, they can also be used in other ways: as
>   floating windows (via a theme with windowIsFloating set) or embedded
>   inside of another activity (using ActivityGroup). There are two
>   methods almost all subclasses of Activity will implement:
>
> onCreate(Bundle) is where you initialize your activity. Most
>   importantly, here you will usually call setContentView(int) with a
>   layout resource defining your UI, and using findViewById(int) to
>   retrieve the widgets in that UI that you need to interact with
>   programmatically. onPause() is where you deal with the user leaving
>   your activity. Most importantly, any changes made by the user should
>   at this point be committed (usually to the ContentProvider holding the
>   data). To be of use with Context.startActivity(), all activity classes
>   must have a corresponding  declaration in their package's
>   AndroidManifest.xml.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: I think this does not answer my question, What I'm asking is that let's say you use `setConetentView(R.layout.content)` and later given an `Activity` is there any way you could retrieve `R.layout.content` you passed to `setConetentView`?