# Get ID of edittext view programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-xml

Here is my XML code for the Edittext and i set id with this name **ettMId**

```
                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ettMId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/login_hint_email_id"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="text|textEmailAddress"
                android:nextFocusDown="@id/etLPassword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppEditTextStyle" />
```

I want that ID  programmatically in my activity class.

I tried this code for getting id

```
   int id=ettMId.getId();
```

But I got below result

```
 If2131230797
```

Actually I want same id name(**ettMId**)  which I had set in XML

Comment: Why can't you check if it's equal to `R.id.ettMId` ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Michael
Yes i do that
with equal condition but i have more then 1k Edittext fields.

Comment: Ok, but even if you get the id as a string you still have 1000 EditText fields. I don't see how having a string would help.

Comment: yeah i knew that
can you please suggest for same?

Comment: what you can do is use Tag and get Tag like   android:tag="ettMId" and in coge ettMId.getTag();

Comment: @IntsabHaider can explain in detail?

Comment: @Arbaz.in in every Editext set Tag also like id and then get tag in your activity as i told you et.getTag() it will return you string Tag

Comment: I also found the more solution from **Marked Tag by Sergey Glotov**,
but accepted answer of that question is not my solution.
The solution what i want is [Link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51356286/5995648).
[Link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18067589/5995648).
i can't delete this question because of @theanilpaudel was invest his time for the answer.
_Thanks @ Sergey Glotov_ for suggestion next time i'll keep it in my mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
String stringID = ettMId.getResources().getResourceName(ettMId.getId());
```

And then you can do String manipulation to extract the exact value of id that will be after `:id/`

Comment: Will this work with minifyEnabled?

Comment: Thanks its working...

Comment: @ZUNJAE yes its working with minifyEnabled true